# 2:1 multiplexer in verilog on an fpga

Tags: fpga, verilog, multiplexer

I'm new to verilog.

I'm trying to implement a 2:1 multiplexer on a FPGA development board (DE1-SOC altera) using built in switches and LEDs.

The following are the assignments that I'm using for the multiplexer, these pins are connected from the FPGA to the switches and leds on the dev board:

```
SW[0] - select
SW[1] - input 1
SW[2] - input 2
LEDR[0] - output
```

This is the verilog

```
module ligths (SW[0], SW[1], SW[2], LEDR[0]);

input SW[0], SW[1], SW[2];

output LEDR[0];

LEDR[0] = ((SW[2] & SW[0]) | (SW[1] & ~SW[0]));  

endmodule
```

Its giving me an error saying that it is

> expecting "." or an identifier near "='.

Am doing something stupid? Can you even create a 2:1 multiplexer out using switches and leds?

Thanks

Comment: Next time put the line number of the error.

Comment: @BrianCarlton: Seriously? You can't find the one "=" in the entire source file? (There are times when I seriously wish we could DOWNvote comments!)

Answer (score 2):

`assign LEDR[0] = SW[0] ? SW[1] : SW[2];`

Its easier to say 
`input [2:0] SW;` too.

What you're missing in the syntax of what you wrote is the `assign`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer using a ternary operator is the best answer to the question. However, I figured I'd give a few more options since you said you're new to Verilog.

**If-Else Statement** (long form of the ternary shown).

```
always @ *
if (SW[0]) {
    LEDR[0] = SW[1];
}
else {
    LEDR[0] = SW[2];
}
```

**Switch Statement** (good for lots of cases).

```
always @ * 
case (SW[0]) 
    0 : LEDR[0] = SW[2];
    default : LEDR[0] = SW[1]; 
endcase
```

The two solutions above are not nearly as elegant as the ternary, but are also valid ways of creating a multiplexer.